# Measuring width of a person with camera

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I'm trying to develop an automatic uniform fitting application using the library emgucv, where the user would be asked to stand in front of the camera to have their whole body pictured,  and from the picture the system will give their standard size (S, M, L, XL, ... , etc). So what I did was use haarcascade to detect the upper body of the user.

my problem is it does not detect precisely how can I improve the system's detecting performance?
(Sorry for my poor English)

here is my code:

```
    void viewImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img = camera.QueryFrame();
        if (img == null)
            return;
        CamImageBox.Image = img;
    }

    private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureProcess == true)
        {
            string data;

            Application.Idle -= viewImage;
            captureProcess = false;
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            //dlg="Image|*.jpg;*png";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                img.ToBitmap().Save(dlg.FileName + ".jpg");
                data = dlg.FileName + ".jpg";
            }
            measureImage();
        }
    }

    void measureImage()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg2 = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg2.Filter = "Image|*.jpg;*png";
        if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(dlg2.FileName);
            Image<Gray, Byte> Gray_Frame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            MCvAvgComp[][] LowerBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                LowerBody,
                1.0,
                10,
                Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                new Size());

            MCvAvgComp[][] UpperBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                UpperBody,
                2.1,
                5,
                Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                new Size());


            foreach (MCvAvgComp Upp_Body in UpperBodyDetect[0])
            {
                frame.Draw(Upp_Body.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                double width=(Upp_Body.rect.Width*0.264583333);
                textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(width));
            }

            foreach (MCvAvgComp Low_Body in LowerBodyDetect[0])
            {
                frame.Draw(Low_Body.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
            }
            CamImageBox.Image = frame;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            camera = new Capture();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            return;
        }
        Application.Idle += viewImage;
        captureProcess = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: :) sorry I forgot to tell this will be used in our school (Philippines) and I think the tallest person that our system will handle is a user with the height 6'5? and the distance will be standard... so I'm really having a hard time figuring this problem @_@